# General Chain Rule for element wise function and Matrix vector product composition

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am trying to apply the general chain rule for a composition of two functions. The first outer function is a element wise function $\phi(x)$ and the second a matrix vector multiplication $W^Tx$:

$$D_x[\phi(W^Tx)]$$

As far as i understand in multivariable calculus for a composition of two functions $D_xf(g(x))$ we get $D_gf(g(x))\cdot D_xg(x)$. Hence i would expect to get $D_x[\phi(W^Tx)] = \phi'(W^Tx)\cdot W^T$, however this is incorrect. Can someone show me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=W^Tx$, so that $\phi = \phi(y)$.

Then the differential in terms of the Hadamard ($\circ$) product is
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \phi'\circ dy \cr
      &= {\rm Diag}(\phi')\,dy \cr
      &= {\rm Diag}(\phi')\,W^Tdx \cr
}$$
And the derivative is $$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}={\rm Diag}(\phi'(W^Tx))\,W^T$$

Comment: can you explain me why there is the Hadamard product?